# slicing the last second word in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i need to write a python script that will count the next-to-last word . my code is:

```
with open('/tmp/values.txt') as f:
    for sentence in f:
        list_sentecne = [sen for sen in sentence.rstrip().split(' ')]

print (list_sentecne)
op = list_sentecne[-2:-2]
print (op)
```

output i got is:-

```
['some', 'line', 'with', 'text']
[]
```

output that i need to get is :

```
with
```

My idea is to use slicing , so i used [-2:-2] such that it will print 2nd word from last in the list but when i run the script, i am getting 'empty list' at the output.

Comment: Use `list_sentecne[-2]`.

Comment: This: `for sentence in f: list_sentecne = [sen for sen in sentence.rstrip().split(' ')]` doesn't make much sense, btw. It will overwrite `list_sentecne` every step through the loop.

Comment: becoz i want to create a list from the data in a file.

Comment: the second slice indice is excluded, no? see: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html and text search "slice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to print from 2nd last element from list -

```
>>> list_sentecne = ['some', 'line', 'with', 'text']
>>> op = list_sentecne[-2:]
>>> print (op)
['with', 'text']
```

if only the 2nd last element

```
>>> list_sentecne = ['some', 'line', 'with', 'text']
>>> op = list_sentecne[-2]
>>> print (op)
'with'
```